# What IDE to use for standalone Javascript debugging?

Tags: javascript

I have a few projects that are scripted via javascript. Not a web pages, unfortunately - just a javascript code that calls a few external methods like `api.Log( "This is log" );`. Is it some IDE exists that i can use to debug such javascript code? I just want to run some unit tests on math and logic so i can break into program, walk it step-by-step and see what is going around. I have tried Visual Studio for Web Developers, aptanta, eclipse - but all of them wants badly to integrade into web browser and debug 'web pages with some javascript' :(. Maybe anyone can suggest a better solution? Maybe some Emacs extension? :) Or IDE / IDE extension / Eclipse distro / IDEA fork i don't know about?

Comment: vscode is the de facto standard (amongst free editors) for js development in my experience, and can certainly debug node apps. https://vscode.dev

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use [Aptana Studio](https://github.com/aptana/studio3)..

Comment: Aptana still looks very webbish...with dom trees and html previews...although I'd probably say it's the best javascript IDE available...

Comment: I have checked it, it still want a web browser and a web page. Not very pleasant javascript debug experience :(